# calculate total price and quantity after generating association rules with python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-mining, apriori

I need some help to calculate total price and quantity for my Basket analysis I used  Apriori algorithm
to get association rules and everything working fine, but I can not get the total price and Quantity

the original data df1

| InvoiceNo | Description | Quantity | InvoiceDate | UnitPrice | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 536370 | ALARM CLOCK BAKELIKE PINK | 24 | 2010 | 3.75 | France |
| 536370 | ALARM CLOCK BAKELIKE Red | 24 | 2010 | 3.75 | France |
| 536370 | ALARM CLOCK BAKELIKE GREEN | 12 | 2010 | 3.75 | France |
| 536370 | PANDA AND BUNNIES STICKER SHEET | 12 | 2010 | 0.85 | France |
| 536370 | STARS GIFT TAPE | 24 | 2010 | 0.65 | France |

after apply Apriori algorithm I get New Dataframe Contain Support , Confidence and Lift.

for example df2

| item1 | item2 | item1_Support | item2_Support | Support | Confidence | Lift |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ALARM CLOCK BAKELIKE GREEN | ALARM CLOCK BAKELIKE PINK | 0.09 | 0.102 | 0.07 | 0.76 | 7.47 |

now I need to add Quantity for each item in df2 with total price.

I try isolate item1 column

```
df_m = pd.DataFrame(df2['Item1'])
```

and rename it

```
df_m = df_m.rename(columns={'Item1':'Description'})
```

and I used merge

```
df_merge1 = pd.merge(df_m,df2, on='Description' , 
                      how='outer')
```

but all I got duplicate item and that it's not useful.
the finel output should contain quantity_item1 column , quantity_item2 coulmn, price item1 , price item2 and the total price
pleas look to df1 for unit price

Any suggestions. Best regards

Comment: What would be expected output in this case?

Comment: in df2 i need Quantity and total price from df1. the column name Quantity for item1 and item2 and total price

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[536370, 'ALARM CLOCK BAKELIKE PINK', 24, 2010, 3.75, 'France'],[536370, 'ALARM CLOCK BAKELIKE Red', 24, 2010, 3.75, 'France'],[536370, 'ALARM CLOCK BAKELIKE GREEN', 12, 2010, 3.75, 'France'],[536370, 'PANDA AND BUNNIES STICKER SHEET', 12, 2010, 0.85, 'France'],[536370, 'STARS GIFT TAPE', 24, 2010, 0.65, 'France']], columns=['InvoiceNo', 'Description', 'Quantity', 'InvoiceDate', 'UnitPrice', 'Country'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[['ALARM CLOCK BAKELIKE GREEN', 'ALARM CLOCK BAKELIKE PINK', 0.09, 0.102, 0.07, 0.76, 7.47]], columns=['item1', 'item2', 'item1_Support', 'item2_Support', 'Support', 'Confidence', 'Lift'])

df = df2.merge(df1, left_on='item1', right_on='Description', sort=False)
df.rename(columns={"UnitPrice": "price_item1", "Quantity": "quantity_item1"}, inplace=True)
df.drop(labels=['InvoiceNo', 'Description', 'InvoiceDate', 'Country'], axis=1, inplace=True)

df_m = df.merge(df1, left_on='item2', right_on='Description', sort=False)
df_m.rename(columns={"UnitPrice": "price_item2", "Quantity": "quantity_item2"}, inplace=True)
df_m.drop(labels=['InvoiceNo', 'Description', 'InvoiceDate', 'Country'], axis=1, inplace=True)

df_m['total_price']=df_m['price_item1']*df_m['quantity_item1'] + df_m['price_item2']*df_m['quantity_item2']
print(df_m)
```

with output as:

```
                        item1                      item2  item1_Support  item2_Support  Support  Confidence  Lift  quantity_item1  price_item1  quantity_item2  price_item2  total_price
0  ALARM CLOCK BAKELIKE GREEN  ALARM CLOCK BAKELIKE PINK           0.09          0.102     0.07        0.76  7.47              12         3.75              24         3.75        135.0
```